com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: denied: requested access to the resource is denied
`I am trying to build docker image and push it to dockerHub using maven.
after running mvn install after doing all the configurations:
pom.xml
Error log
`

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.2.5
 

com.example.mavenDocker
spring-boot-docker-maven
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
spring-boot-docker-maven
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.13</version>
            <configuration>
                <repository>ayusharyan13/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                <buildArgs>
                    <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                </buildArgs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                        <goal>push</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>spring-boot-docker-maven</finalName>
</build>


`
#Dockerfile
`# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:17
Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/spring-boot-docker-maven.jar spring-boot-docker-maven.jar
Run the jar file
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","spring-boot-docker-maven.jar"]`
